# How to convert to Higher Order Function?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, higher-order-functions

I am trying to convert the below to HOFs, but below is the best I came up with. Turns out to be standard. How can I better use functional programming?

1st attempt:

```
const privileges = {
        canAccessProject: 'Project',
        canAccessReport: 'Report'
    },
    licenses = {
        core: 'Core',
        review: 'Review'
    };

const getPrivileges = (access) => getPermissions(access, privileges);
const getLicenses = (access) => getPermissions(access, licenses);
const getPermissions = (access, entity) => Object.keys(access).map((p) => (access[p] ? entity[p] : '')).join(', ');

// output: "Project, Report"
console.log(getPrivileges({canAccessProject: true, canAccessReport; true })) 

// output: "Review"
console.log(getLicenses({review: true, core; false }))
```

2nd attempt:

```
const getPrivileges = (access) => getPermissions(access)(privileges)
const getLicenses = (access) => getPermissions(access)(licenses);
const getPermissions = (access) => (entity) => Object.keys(access).map((p) => (access[p] ? entity[p] : '')).join(', ');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, `getPermissions` could have the entity as it's first parameter, and could return a function taking `access` then:

```
 const getPermissions = (entity) => (access) => Object.keys(access).map((p) => (access[p] ? entity[p] : '')).join(', ');

 const getLicenses = getPermissions(licenses);
```